# Combinatorics problem with bit-strings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, bit-strings

When only three types of bit strings `0`, `10`,`11` are available, how many valid $7$-bit strings can be represented? For example, the bit string `0101110`, which is composed of `0`, `10`, `11`, `10`, is a valid bit string, but `1100101` is invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $f(n)$ as the number of valid $n$-bit strings and define the empty string as valid.  So $f(0)=f(1)=1$.  We can create a valid string of length $n$ by taking a string of length $n-1$ and appending "$0$" or by taking a string of length $n-2$ and appending either "$10$" or "$11$".  So, we have $f(n)=f(n-1)+2f(n-2)$.  From here, we get

$$f(2)=f(1)+2f(0)=1+2=3$$
$$f(3)=f(2)+2f(1)=3+2=5$$
$$f(4)=f(3)+2f(2)=5+6=11$$
$$f(5)=f(4)+2f(3)=11+10=21$$
$$f(6)=f(5)+2f(4)=21+22=43$$
$$f(7)=f(6)+2f(5)=43+42=85$$

Answer (score 5):

The available strings form whats called a "prefix code", which means that no string is the prefix of another string.  This allows us to create a simple algorithm that determines if a bit string is valid or not. Think of the bit string as a stream.  Read in a character.  If it is `0`, discard it and move on to the next character.  If it is a `1`, then discard it *and* the next character.

In the first case, we are removing an instance of the `0` string.  In the second, we are removing an instance of either `10` or `11`.

This process only fails if you read in a `1` but there is no character following it.

Therefore, the only invalid strings are strings which end in a single `1`.  Can you finish the problem from here?

Edit: @YawarRaza7349 pointed out a potential misinterpretation; I'll complete this solution to avoid that.

- Since all invalid strings end in `1`, we know that all strings ending in `0` are valid.  This already gives us $2^6=64$ valid strings.
- Next, the only way for a valid string to end in a `1` is for the last two characters to be `11`.  If we remove these characters, we are left with $5$ characters that also form a valid string.
- Thus we can apply the same argument again.  If the last of these $5$ characters is `0`, the string is valid.  This gives $2^4=16$ valid strings.
- Iterating again, we have $3$ characters which form a valid string and there are $2^2=4$ possibilities.
- Finally, we have just a single character string that is valid, there is only $2^0=1$ option.
- Summing, we have $2^6+2^4+2^2=64+16+4+1=85$.

Comment: Your last paragraph could be read as implying that the answer is the number of 7-bit strings that end in `1`, which isn't correct. Valid strings where `11` was consumed last also end in `1`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the number of 7-bit strings that _don't_ end in `1`".

Comment: @YawarRaza7349 thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting alternative to the one in Mike's answer. Another fix though: you need to take one more step and add $2^0$ (for the string `0111111`). (I'm also not sure what you mean by "excluding the empty string"; it wasn't explicitly excluded, it wasn't counted like for the same reason all other strings that aren't 7 bits long weren't counted.)

Comment: I think this formulation uses a recurrence relation $g(n)$ defining the number of *invalid* n-bit strings, i.e. the complement of Mike's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The numbers 11 and 10 have 2 digits(2 bits) and 0 has a single digit(1 bit).
The 7 bits can be formed in 4 cases:  1) three 2 bits and one 1 bit
                                      2) two 2 bits and three 1 bits
                                      3) one 2 bit and five 1 bits
                                      4) zero 2 bits and seven 1 bits.

Case 1:
_ _ _ 0   the first three blanks can be filled in 8 ways(2 ways for 1st blank{because it 
                can be filled by 10 or 11}, 2 ways in 2nd and the same goes for the 3rd).

so by product rule 2*2*2=8 ways

Case 2:
_ _ 0 0 0  the first two blanks can be filled in 4 ways( 2 ways for 1st and in two for 
                                                                                  2nd).

so by product rule we have 2*2 = 4.

Case 3:
_ 0 0 0 0 0   the first blank can be filled in 2 ways(with 10 or 11).

so this equals 2.

Case 4:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0   this is applicable in only one way.

(i didn't have the need to choose the one bit because it is 0 for sure)

now to obtain the final answer add all the cases.

which equals 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15.

therefore there 15 strings.

I am happy to receive any corrections if this is wrong :)

Comment: I think the problem might be that the zeros don't have to all be at the end.

Comment: but it wasn't mentioned right?

Comment: The valid example the OP mentioned in the beginning, `0` `10` `11` `10`, starts with a `0`, and thus is not counted in any of your cases.